# How to set log levels for Flutter in VS Code?

Tags: flutter, dart

**Is there a way to adjust log levels for Flutter in VS Code?**

I want to set it to 'TRACE' or 'INFO' if possible because I am trying to debug something.

If there is no way to adjust log levels for Flutter in VS Code, then is there a way to do that with CLI?